I want my JS to be executed when i'm loading my page HTML through PhantomJS
I'm trying to load my HTML until my JS code is executed to translate my HTML using PHP. I would then like to retrieve the content of this translated HTML. I've done a lot of research but I can't get it.
Here's the code of my HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Translate Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <p>This example displays a simple translate button, with no text.</p>
        <p>This example displays a simple translate button, with no text.</p>
        <div class="notranslate">
            <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
            <p>
                A particle is kept at rest at the top of a sphere of diameter \(42 m\). When disturbed slightly,
                it slides down. At what height \( h \) from the bottom, the particle will leave the sphere <br>
                (a) \( 14m \)<br>
                (b) \( 16m \)<br>
                (c) \( 35m \)<br>
                (d) \( 70m \)
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function translateContent() {
            const allTextNodes = getAllTextNodes(document.body);
            const textContent = allTextNodes.map(node => node.textContent.trim()).join(' ');

            // Translate content to French using Google Translate
            fetch('https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=fr&dt=t&q=' + encodeURIComponent(textContent))
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    const translatedText = data[0].map(sentence => sentence[0]);
                    replaceTextNodes(allTextNodes, translatedText.join(' '));
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error translating content:', error));
        }

        function getAllTextNodes(element) {
            const walker = document.createTreeWalker(element, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
            const textNodes = [];

            while (walker.nextNode()) {
                textNodes.push(walker.currentNode);
            }

            return textNodes;
        }

        function replaceTextNodes(nodes, newText) {
            let currentIndex = 0;
            nodes.forEach(node => {
                if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    const originalText = node.textContent.trim();
                    const newTextSlice = newText.slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + originalText.length);
                    node.textContent = newTextSlice;
                    currentIndex += originalText.length;
                }
            });
        }

        // Trigger translation on page load
        window.onload = translateContent;
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I had tried this:
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

// Create a PhantomJS client instance
$client = Client::getInstance();

// Set the path to the PhantomJS binary
$client->getEngine()->setPath('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs');

// Open a webpage
$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest('translateHTMLUsingJs2.html', 'GET');

// Set the timeout for script execution (in milliseconds)
$request->setTimeout(2000);

// Render the webpage
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

// Send the request and receive the response
$client->send($request, $response);

// Output the rendered HTML content
echo $response->getContent();

But it doesn't work as I'd hoped and this library returned the same HTML code without the translation. I don't know if you can help me do it in PHP, but Can you help me to do it in PHP please?
Anyone will be a great help. Feel free to comment or give me a solution...

Hi, welcome to SO! Maybe I don't see it, but when does that PHP script of yours run and what do you want to achieve with it? PhantomJS is a headless browser, not a tool to translate something from one language into another. And how is it related to the rest of your code? Your HTML is just what it is, your JS calls out to Google, not to a PHP script.

@Davi Yes. I know but the problem is that I would like the html page to be displayed so that the js executes automatically to translate the html file into the php code so that I get a translated html. Can you please help me?

Does the window.onload = translateContent; not do that already? What's happening when you run the code currently? Are you saying you are only executing this code via phantomJS, not via a browser? It's all a bit unclear - remember we can't see your screen or read your mind.

P.S. What's the context for this? Have you got some static HTML pages that you need to translate as a one-off job, or something? Because this isn't normally how you'd approach having a translation or multi-language feature in a website.

@ADyson this code works perfectly for the translation of this file on the browser. I just want it to execute in the browser when using php. Can you help me please?

It's not clear what I just want it to execute in the browser when using php means? If you're using PHP and PhantomJS, then a browser is not involved. Are you saying you want the JS to be executed when you're loading this page through PhantomJS. Is that what isn't working currently? I suspect the answer below by Daniels118 is probably on the right track, but for future reference you could do a much better job of making the question clear and unambiguous. And you didn't actually answer my question about context.

@ADyson yes, that's exactly what I want. But the Daniels118 code doesn't work too well for me. Can you help me with your rating?

I don't know anything about PhantomJS I'm afraid. Was just trying to get you to ask a clearer question, so it's easier to answer, and more useful for future readers. You should [edit] your post to clarify it, now we've got closer to what you're actually trying to ask. I would note though what Daniels118 said - PhantomJS is archived. You may want to find a headless browser which is more up to date and actively maintained. This may give you better results.

@ADyson I've just changed the title and body of my issue. What should I do to get a lot of answers to fix this issue as soon as possible??

Thanks. You have to be patient. Stackoverflow is an encyclopaedia, not a helpdesk. The questions and answers are primarily intended to have long term value to the whole community- that is the goal of the site. Your personal deadlines or urgency are not the community's concern. W are volunteers. People will answer the question if/when they have the time/inclination/knowledge. All you can do is make the question as clear, focused and well-researched as possible so it makes it easier to answer. If you need this work doing on a short timescale then hire a freelance programmer to work on it

I understand that your PHP code uses a wrapper for PhantomJS, which in turn is a headless browser.
I guess that your goal is to let PhantomJS execute Google Translate over a web page, so that you can extract the translated text from PHP.
You correctly thought that the headless browser needs some time to let the Google Translate code do its work, but you have used the wrong parameter for this. The "timeout" is about the total max execution time, you need a delay instead, or, even better, a lazy saving of the DOM. The php-phantomjs reference has a specific example to do this:
use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

$client = Client::getInstance();
$client->isLazy(); // Tells the client to wait for all resources before rendering

$request  = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest();
$request->setTimeout(5000); // Will render page if this timeout is reached and resources haven't finished

note the "isLazy" call.
Side notes

PhantomJS project has been archived since 2018, it most likely won't be supported anymore, so if you will face a problem in the future, you may need to move to another library and change most of your code;
Google Translate has its own API (which may have a cost) to make translations from a program; using the translator this way may violate the terms of use, and possibily lead to human verification, IP blocking, and legal actions, so make it at your own risk.


I've added it, it doesn't work. It returns the content of the original HTML file. The translation has not been done. What should I do in this case?
